# jquery append' called on an object

Tags: jquery

Why do i get the follow error from my browser:

TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.

?

how can i fix it?

MY Jquery code

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit_save-btn", function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this).closest('form')[0]; 
    for (i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) 
    {
        if (form.elements[i].type == 'file') 
        {
            if (form.elements[i].value == '') {
                form.elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(form.elements[i]);
            }
        }
    }



    var form_data = new FormData(form);
    var act = "edit";


    form_data.append('agntID', "4");
    form_data.append('act', 'edit');

//  form_data.push({name: 'agntID', value: "4"});   
//  form_data.push({name: 'act', value: 'edit'});   
    });
```

HTML

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="4" class="item">

    <div class="col-md-2 item_logo"><input name="file[]" type="file"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 item_name"><input name="agnt[name]" value="Agency 2" type="text"><span>*</span></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 item_mainEmail"><input name="agnt[mainEmail]" value="email@gmail.com" type="text"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 item_contact"><textarea type="text" name="agnt[contact]">some details</textarea></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 panel-menu">
        <span class="edit_msg"></span>

        <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw edit_form-loader"></i>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success edit_save-btn">Save</a>

    </div>

</form>
```

............ ..........................

Answer (score 0):

I change my AJAX code:

$.ajax ({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'ajax/agnts-control.php',
  data: form_data,
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: false,
  cache: false,
  processData:false,